# Component not re-render when dispatch action in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am learning about Redux and ran into the problem below. My component doesn't re-render when dispatch action `changeStatus`, but works when dispatch `actionRemove`. Let me know why? Thanks.

code here
`reducer`

```
const HandleTaskReducer = (state = initializeState, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case addTask: {
            let list = state.tasks;
            list.push(action.payload);
            localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(list));
            return {
                ...state,
                tasks: list
            };
        }
        case completeTask: {
            let list = state.tasks;
            let index = list.findIndex((value => value.id === action.payload));
            if (index > -1) {
                list[index].status = true;
                localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(list));
            }
            return {
                ...state,
                tasks: list
            };
        }
        case removeTask: {
            let list = state.tasks;
            let index = list.findIndex((value => value.id === action.payload));
            if (index > -1) {
                list.splice(index, 1);
                localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(list));
            }
            return {
                ...state,
                tasks: list
            };
        }
        default: {
            return {...state};
        }
    }
}
```

this is code in component

```
const TaskItemComponent = props => {
    const className = !props.task.status ? 'item-task bg-grey' : 'item-task bg-grey success';

    const removeTask = () => {
        props.remove(props.task.id);
    }

    const changeStatus = () => {
        props.completeTask(props.task.id);
    }
    return (
        <div className={className}>
            <div className="content-task">
                <h3>{props.task.name}</h3>
                <p>{props.task.description}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="action-task">
                {!props.task.status && <button onClick={changeStatus} className="btn">Complete</button>}
                <button className="btn" onClick={removeTask}>Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        remove: id => {
            dispatch(actionRemove(id))
        },
        completeTask: id => {
            dispatch(actionComplete(id));
            console.log(id)
        }
    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(TaskItemComponent);
```

this is ListTaskComponent

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import TaskItemComponent from "./TaskItemComponent";
import {connect} from "react-redux";

const ListTaskComponent = props => {
    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setTasks(props.taskState.tasks);
    }, []);

    const list = tasks.map(value =>
        <TaskItemComponent
            key={value.id.toString()} task={value}/>
    );
    return (
        <section id="wrap-task" className="mt-3">
            {list}
        </section>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        taskState: state.taskReducer,
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(ListTaskComponent)
```

Comment: which component should re-render? you did pass null here `connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(TaskItemComponent)`

Comment: I updated my post, see ListTaskComponent, as far as I know if ListTaskComponent re-render then list will be updated new

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely that you're violate the "single source of truth" principal.

You do this with the following lines of code:

> ```
> const ListTaskComponent = props => {
>     const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
>
>     useEffect(() => {
>         setTasks(props.taskState.tasks);
>     }, []);
> ```

So, what is the plan here? You receive a list of `taskState.tasks` from the Redux store. Which is is copied into the components own state. What happens if `taskState.tasks` changes? The `ListTaskComponent` component will re-render, but since `tasks` is only set on component mount the value will never update.

The problem is easily fixed by removing the local state.

```
const ListTaskComponent = props => {
    const tasks = props.taskState.tasks;
```

The above should fix the "single source of truth" principal. However if the first thing we do is map the state to a value you might as well move this change into `mapStateToProps` to simplify the actual component.

```
const ListTaskComponent = ({ tasks }) => {
    const list = tasks.map(value => 
        <TaskItemComponent key={value.id.toString()} task={value} />
    );

    return (
        <section id="wrap-task" className="mt-3">{list}</section>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ tasks: state.taskReducer.tasks });

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(ListTaskComponent);
```

---

Another issue I can see has to do with the reducer itself. Reducers should not mutate the previous state, yet in your code I can spot mutations to the original state:

> ```
> let list = state.tasks;
> list.push(action.payload);
> ```
>
> ```
> let list = state.tasks;
> let index = list.findIndex((value => value.id === action.payload));
> if (index > -1) {
>     list[index].status = true;
> ```
>
> ```
> let list = state.tasks;
> let index = list.findIndex((value => value.id === action.payload));
> if (index > -1) {
>     list.splice(index, 1);
> ```

I suggest reading [Writing Reducers](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers#writing-reducers) which explains the rules that reducers should follow and also gives some examples.

Coming back to your code you could write the above code blocks in the following manner:

```
let list = [...state.tasks];
list.push(action.payload);
// or
let list = [...state.tasks, action.payload];
```

```
let list = [...state.tasks];
let index = list.findIndex((value => value.id === action.payload));
if (index > -1) {
    list[index] = { ...list[index], status: true };
// or
let list = state.tasks.map(value => {
   if (value.id !== action.payload) return value;
   return { ...value, status: true };
});
```

```
let list = [...state.tasks];
let index = list.findIndex((value => value.id === action.payload));
if (index > -1) {
    list.splice(index, 1);
// or
let list = state.tasks.filter(value => value.id !== action.payload);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check `reducer`, u did not anything with `changeStatus` !

Comment: I checked, it went into reducer, localStorage was updated.

Comment: Bro, it's not an answer, type something like this in the comment.

Comment: Yeah,, but I can not add comments like you. `You must have 50 reputation to comment` .

Answer (score 0):

Try change your `ListTaskComponent` to below should solve the issue, not need `useState` just use them directly.

```
const ListTaskComponent = props => (
        <section id="wrap-task" className="mt-3">
          {props.taskState.tasks.map(value =>
            <TaskItemComponent key={value.id} task={value}/>
           )}
        </section>
    )
```